# How to calculate time-frequency domain renyi entropy?

Tags: python, arrays, signal-processing, entropy

[image]

This is the definition of Renyi entropy in the time-frequency domain. I will use this function to calculate the Renyi entropy of a spectrogram. px(t,f) will be the outcome of this spectrogram. For example, `array([[5.85959171e-01, 7.95627554e+00, 1.22937578e-01, ..., 1.82902033e+00, 5.96424909e-01, 3.20172883e+00], [8.12774889e+02, 8.03338062e+02, 6.11289787e+02, ..., 5.36101542e+02, 5.27223899e+01, 1.55881316e+02], [2.19951771e+01, 4.11390671e+02, 3.04105310e+02, ..., 1.01747040e+02, 2.36618805e+01, 8.56933907e+01], ..., [6.25524855e-04, 4.55459276e-04, 2.70485227e-04, ..., 1.40541362e-03, 1.38247253e-03, 4.60767521e-04], [1.16518569e-04, 1.56417512e-05, 6.71531675e-05, ..., 4.81702798e-04, 2.16510385e-04, 3.43761986e-04], [5.82912053e-05, 2.61144404e-05, 5.96264388e-05, ..., 1.23245212e-04, 3.72841550e-04, 1.46325938e-04]])`
So, can anyone please help me code this function using this array?

Comment: A quick search got me into this library https://dit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measures/other/renyi_entropy.html . Python has libraries for everything, you don't need to code whatsoever for yourself.

Comment: Thanks but I know that one. It is for time-series data. Here I am using time-frequency domain data. That confused me about how to convert it above function.

Answer (score 0):

you may simply try the following (in matlab notation)

`log(sum(sum((tfd.^3))))` where `tfd`: Time-frequency 2d array

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).